# Get innerText from iframe from parent

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, innertext

Hi I'm adding a number of iframes to my page. Iframes contain only one value and I would like to get it form the parent. I tried many of the answers posted here on the stack overflow but none of them works for me. Below I attached the image so you can see how is the iframe included in the page. I would like to get the value in the red frame so I can use it later.

[image]

The code:

```
  var graphUrls = tmpSource.getGetFeatureInfoUrl(
    graphCoor, viewResolution, 'EPSG:3857', {'INFO_FORMAT': 'text/html'});
  var frr = document.createElement("iframe");
  frr.onload = function(){
    var jjj = $("iframe body a").text()
    var kkk = $("iframe body #ras-val").text()
    console.log("jjj ", jjj)
    console.log("kkk ", kkk)
  };
  frr.id = sourceParams.year + "-" + sourceParams.month + "-" + sourceParams.day;        
  frr.src = graphUrls
  document.body.appendChild(frr);
```

Comment: have you tried using jQuery? $("iframe body a").text() ?

Comment: or $("iframe body #ras-val").text()?

Comment: Hey, your solution returns only empty string. I tried also $("#"+String(frames[i].id)).contents().find("a"). This returns an object that has innerText value stored somewhere deep down but only in Edge, in Chrome this string is also empty? Is it possible that my iframes are not loaded yet when I try to access the value? Why then different behaviour in different browsers? How would I wait until iframe is loaded if this is the case?

Comment: did you use document.ready or window.ready? If you used document.ready try to change it for window.ready.

Comment: no, tried to use iframe.onload = function... I updated my question so you can see what and how am I doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the returned url is **from the same domain as your main document**, and only in this case,
then you can pass the [`contentDocument`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLIFrameElement/contentDocument) of your iframe as the second parameter of [`$(selector, context)`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery1).

```js
// frame is you iframeElement
$('#ras-val', frame.contentDocument).text()
```

[**As a fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/2rvnzadn/) since StackSnippet's null origined frames won't allow us to access inner frames...

Note that the selector will then be relative to this *context*, so you won't pass `"iframe body a"` but just `"body a"`.

And in case the url is not from the same domain, then your front-end code is not allowed to access this document for security reasons.

Comment: Nice, this works and I actually get everything that is inside iframe as string. One more thing: What if I would like to access the value of the var rasVal that is in iframes script? how would I do that? Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Alešinar If this variable has been declared in the global scope, then it will be attached to the Window object, that you can retrieve with `frame.contentWindow`. If it has been defined in a scoped function, then you can't retrieve it.